# why am i getting this error message when i start my_app server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, ejs

```
node:events:304
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1286:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1334:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1420:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/abubakar/Desktop/Node/express/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abubakar/Desktop/Node/express/my_app.js:24:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1313:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: like it says, "address already in use"

Answer (score 0):

Error: listen EADDRINUSE is coming as your port 3000 is being used by another instance or application.Terminate that application or change your port to a different value like 3001 or 3002.

Comment: node:events:304
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1286:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1334:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1420:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/abubakar/Desktop/Node/express/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abubakar/Desktop/Node/express/my_app.js:24:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs

Comment: @AbubahkarSadeeq Please don't add information like this as a comment. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64553467/edit) your question to add additional information, and format it so it's readable.

Comment: Thank you, I am a newbie

Comment: @AbubahkarSadeeq share your code where you are initializing the node server.

Answer (score 0):

Open your **Task Manager** and check if any of the application is using `3000` port. Terminate that process and then run the application. If that's not do-able, restart your system.